# FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException NHiberNate

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I get an error like this when writing unit test
[image]

My product class is like this. I added virtual.
[image]

My map is like this.

[image]

SqlServerHelper like this.

[image]

I am using vs code 2022. I'm developing with Net 6.0 entity framework.
I am getting this error while doing unit test. No errors in codes.
Is it a problem with the version? Or Is there a logical error.
what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I wrote Db link instead of Northwind Context. :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).